# How to handle long text in preferences on Android?

Tags: android, textview, android-preferences, preferenceactivity, longtext

### Background

I'm making an app that has some settings, and I want to use the built in PreferenceActivity or PreferenceFragment for the job

### The problem

Some of the preferences have a long title which I cannot shorten, plus I think that if I ever localize the app (translate to multiple languages) I would face the same problem (for example in German, which has quite long words, sometimes).

What you get in this situation is just the beginning of the text and then "..." (or less dots, which doesn't make much sense btw) in the end of it.

Example:

[image]

### What I've tried

I know that the PreferenceActivity extends from ListActivity, so I can change its adapter to whatever I wish, but that would remove the way it works.

I also know that I can extend from each of the types of the preferences classes, use the "onCreateView" method to have a reference to the created view and then access its children, but this is weird, no? I mean, it's almost like assuming that it will never change the way it looks.

EDIT: Here's a sample code of what I've tried:

Extend from each of the preferences classes, and in each of them , use:

```
...
@Override
protected View onCreateView(final ViewGroup parent)
  {
  final View view=super.onCreateView(parent);
  ViewUtil.handlePreferenceTitleTextView(view);
  return view;
  }
...

//ViewUtil.java :

private void handlePreferenceTitleTextView(final View v)
  {
  final TextView titleTextView=(TextView)v.findViewById(android.R.id.title);
  if(titleTextView!=null)
    titleTextView.setSingleLine(false);
  }
```

It works, but I don't think it's recommended as Google might change the way preferences views work.

### The question

How to handle long text in preferences' titles  on Android ?

Is it possible to make it have an ellipsize / marquee (so that it will have an animation to show everything) ? Or maybe auto fit the font size? Or set it to have word wrap ? Or a horizontal scrollView that will allow the user to scroll to read the rest of the text?

Is there maybe a convention of how to handle such cases? Maybe long clicking to show a toast/dialog for seeing the whole text?

Comment: I am interesting in this question. with some google search I found these threads http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4925194/whats-the-maximum-size-for-an-android-shared-preference-value and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3199910/android-sharedpreferences-limitations.I am waiting for the answer

Comment: @WilliamKinaan No, I'm not talking about the sharedPreferences. I'm talking about UI. the preferenceActivity has all of its textual views to have a limit on their titles. Currently, the only solution that works for me on this case is to extend from each of the preferences classes, and find out the TextView with the id "R.id.title" and change its attributes to whatever I want, but this is a weird solution.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, could you please write the answer when you find it, ofc if no one else has answered it.

Comment: Yes, I will write a tiny sample of what i've tried, which seems to work fine, but I don't think it's recommended to use it.

Comment: Any reason to not make up a short name (users will prefer it anyway) and describe what it does in `android:summary`?

Comment: @el_bhm As I've written, sometimes it's very hard as some words are very long. This is especially problematic with localizations, as some languages have very long words (like German).

Comment: I am of thought that a work on a proper translation and usage of a language will give you less headache than reinventing the wheel to fit longer words on multiple screen sizes. I am not a native speaker of German, know little of it, but from what is known to me Germans do love short words for the sheer amount of 15+ letter words.

Comment: @el_bhm but there are also screens with small amount of space, which cannot show even english words. Also, in case of a switchPreference, there is about 50% less space than usual (because of the switch view and the padding).

Comment: I think the problem is very annoying and frequent for small screens. Would you mind to post the workaround you mentioned in your comments as an extended answer?

Comment: @Stan For which case exactly? What kind of UI component do you need help with? For most of them I've made my own workaround (which I hope works well on all devices). You can check my app to see what I've done there if you wish: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lb.app_manager

Comment: For the case shown in the question exactly (titles of switches are truncated (whereas titles of checkboxes - do not, BTW)). I'm going to play with custom preference layouts if your approach will seem too complicated. Is the "EDIT" in your question - the final workaround you use?

Comment: @Stan If all you wish to handle is the switch/checkbox preference, you can use what I've done, but I asked this since I didn't find an official way to handle it. The sample code works for me on all of the preferences, but you need to extend each of them. Also, BTW, if you wish to use a SwitchPreference whenever possible, you can use this post (which is also a workaround) : http://stackoverflow.com/a/15855157/878126 . I've even made a post about this issue to Google: https://code.google.com/p/android-developer-preview/issues/detail?id=616

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### **2021:** When using androidx.preference (likely what everyone has)

### You can simply use `app:singleLineTitle="false"`

```
<Preference
        app:key="your_key"
        app:singleLineTitle="false"
        app:title="LONG TITLEEEEEEE EEEEEEEEE EEEEEEEEEEEEEEE" />
```

Works for Switches etc too

Comment: Seems to work well. Thank you. But is there a way to set it for all?

Comment: OK I've updated my answer (which was wrong, it seems, but maybe was right in the beginning, not sure) to have a solution for all preferences.

Answer (score 6):

This is my solution of the problem for specific case of the `SwitchPreference` and for a preference in general.

First of all, I should note that for API levels before 14 it looks like preference titles were multiline by default - at least I did not see any problems with long titles in Android 2.3.3. In newer versions of Android this behaviour has changed to forced single line title.

The workaround is to tweek the `SwitchPreference` or any other type of preference's layout a bit.

In the preference screen file add the `android:layout` attribute for required preference, for example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <PreferenceCategory android:title="@string/prefs_category">
    <SwitchPreference
        android:key="keyOfThePreference"
        android:title="@string/pref_title"
        android:switchTextOn="@string/pref_on"
        android:switchTextOff="@string/pref_off"
        android:summaryOn="@string/pref_enabled"
        android:summaryOff="@string/pref_disabled"
        android:layout="@layout/preference_multiline"
        />
        ...
```

Next, provide the `preference_multiline.xml` with alternative layout. I used a modified version of the standard `preference.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Layout for a Preference in a PreferenceActivity. The
     Preference is able to place a specific widget for its particular
     type in the "widget_frame" layout. -->
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingRight="?android:attr/scrollbarSize"
    android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+android:id/icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="6dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="6dip"
        android:layout_marginBottom="6dip"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <TextView android:id="@+android:id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:singleLine="false"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:fadingEdge="horizontal" />

        <TextView android:id="@+android:id/summary"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@android:id/title"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@android:id/title"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textColor="?android:attr/textColorSecondary"
            android:maxLines="4" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <!-- Preference should place its actual preference widget here. -->
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+android:id/widget_frame"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="vertical" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Here I deliberately changed `android:singleLine` value in the title's `TextView` from `true` to `false`. This does the job.

Comment: This is a safer solution, but on the other hand, it doesn't respect the default look of the device's OS , as it forces it to look as you've chosen. I guess each solution has its own advantages and disadantages...

Comment: You're right. And yes, Android can change in newer versions in such a way that introduce unwanted side effects (as it's mentioned in the edited answer regarding "multilineness" of preference titles), so having custom layout gives full control over the app. After all many developers use custom preferences.

Comment: Great! This is working perfectly fine. But there is this warning: `android:singleLine is deprecated: False is the default, so just remove the attribute`. Should I remove it?

Comment: @HammadNasir, you may try it. This can be version specific.

Comment: Link to the original layout in AOSP: https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/layout/preference.xml

Answer (score 2):

Based on solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67337810/878126) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51568782/878126) , this is a way to set it for all, if anyone wishes:

```
abstract class BasePreferenceFragment : PreferenceFragmentCompat() {

    private fun applyOperationsForAllPreferences(preference: Preference) {
        // preference.isIconSpaceReserved = false //you can add this too, if you don't want icons space
        preference.isSingleLineTitle = false
        if (preference is PreferenceGroup)
            for (i in 0 until preference.preferenceCount)
                applyOperationsForAllPreferences(preference.getPreference(i))
    }

    override fun setPreferenceScreen(preferenceScreen: PreferenceScreen?) {
        preferenceScreen?.let { applyOperationsForAllPreferences(it) }
        super.setPreferenceScreen(preferenceScreen)
    }

}
```

Comment: Would be sweet to know "how" this solves the question (and the 6 subquestions asked)

Comment: @CaptainCrunch Sorry I don't remember. as for the questions, you might be able to extend from it and handle the Views yourself.

Comment: @CaptainCrunch You are correct. This doesn't help. no idea why I wrote it. Maybe for some time it handled it, but now it's not. No idea what's going on.

Comment: @CaptainCrunch Anyway updated now with a nicer way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't want to copy-paste a layout, so I've ended up subclassing the preference:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.preference.CheckBoxPreference;
import android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceViewHolder;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class CustomCheckboxPreference extends CheckBoxPreference {

  public CustomCheckboxPreference(Context context) {
    super(context);
  }

  public CustomCheckboxPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
  }

  public CustomCheckboxPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
  }

  public CustomCheckboxPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
  }

  @Override
  public void onBindViewHolder(PreferenceViewHolder holder) {
    super.onBindViewHolder(holder);
    TextView title = (TextView) holder.findViewById(android.R.id.title);
    if (title != null) {
      title.setSingleLine(false);
    }
  }

}
```

Then just use it in your `prefs.xml`:

```
<android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceScreen ...>
  <android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceCategory ...>
    <com.example.CustomCheckboxPreference
      ...
      />
```

Comment: That's the same exact code of I wrote in the question. Same also exists in the library I've made, here: https://github.com/AndroidDeveloperLB/MaterialPreferenceLibrary

Comment: Yes it's the same (except that I use the support preferences)... I didn't even read the question, haha.