# how to create a custom switch control in android

Tags: java, android, xml

I want to create a custom switch control.

It's custom because I want to support Android min version: 2.2

Is there any native control I can inherit from?

Seekbar?

I want it to be like a toggleButton, but with the ability to both:

(1) move on single click

(2) be dragged right or left

Comment: Please see solution to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9920709 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9505901

Comment: Check the links in my answer

Answer (score 1):

You can inherit from the `CheckBox` or the `ToggleButton` views. They work very similarly. You will need to make some drawables for your View

**OR**

You can use any of these libraries which bring the switch to Android 2.2

https://github.com/BoD/android-switch-backport

https://github.com/pellucide/Android-Switch-Demo-pre-4.0/tree/master/android-switch-demo

https://github.com/ankri/SwitchCompatLibrary

Answer (score 0):

SeekBar? Rather not. Most of SeekBar's code is logic for flattening the background drawable while preserving clip drawables.

99% of cases where in some other framework you would build a custom widget, in Android is just changing the background drawable. I believe you should be fine with just using a ToggleButton without any text but with some custom statelist drawable in the background.